# Soft bricked device fails to boot into recovery, both through key combo and fastboot

Tags: unbricking

I have a Micromax Canvas 2.2 A114 which is soft bricked. I am trying to get into recovery mode after flashing CWM Recovery image using fastboot with the following command:

```
# fastboot flash recovery /tmp/recovery.img
```

The command gives the following result:

```
sending 'recovery' (6144 KB)...
OKAY [  0.233s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  1.098s]
finished. total time: 1.332s
```

However, when I try to get into the recovery mode, it doesn't boot into recovery and go into reboot again having infinite loop cycles.

How do I fix my phone?

#### Edit

Attempting to directly boot into the recovery doesn't work. Console remains stuck on `booting...` and device doesn't boot at all.

```
# fastboot boot /tmp/recovery.img
downloading 'boot.img'... 
OKAY [ 0.204s] 
booting...
```

Comment: The chipset your device has is supported by SP Flash Tools. Find the ROM [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-micromax-stock-rom-models) and flash it using that tool. You can also flash the recovery partition alone and see if the device reboots into your CWM recovery this time.

Answer (score 1):

Solved...!!

First of all thanks to @Firelord for pointing me to SP Flash Tools and giving the link of stock ROM.

In case anyone ever stuck with this problem in future, I would like to tell I got my phone recovered by following this tutorial:

[How to Unbrick every MTK China Phone ! Preloader / SP Flashtool Fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3TmXtOA0IA)